# Installed pywin 32 -- still getting error -- "No module named win32com.client."

Tags: python

I'm trying to install pywin32 (32 bit 2.7) so that I can run python from ArcGIS 10.2.1 (32 bit), and have access to the pywin modules. But I am getting the error  "No module named win32com.client." I installed from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20221/).

It created a whole separate installation folder, so if I run pywin from there, and try to import arcpy, it can't find the module. And if I go into ArcGIS and try to import win32com.client, it can't find the module. So I'm not sure how to install it so that I can get all the modules loaded into the LIB of my ArcGIS installation.

I have no admin priviledges at all, I have to ask an admin, so I can't even see the env variables. But I know in ArcGIS, it's running python from that ArcGIS 10.2 folder. Was this installed wrong? Or do you have any ideas on how I can fix this? I have to edit ArcFM features, and apparently you can't do it via python without pywin.

[image: Installation Folders]

Comment: I would try and use `pip install pypiwin32` if you could.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34993224/2258  Not sure if it will fix your issue, however.

Answer (score 0):

```
python -m pip install pywin32
```

Works fine on Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)] on win32.

The package named [`pypiwin32`](https://pypi.org/project/pypiwin32/) looks abandoned as it lags behind in version (221 vs [224](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/)) and lacks a description.

Comment: ArcGIS only runs on Python 2.7

Comment: @klewis Python 2 will be unsupported next year.

Comment: ArcGIS Pro runs with Python 3.x. ArcGIS will never run on Python 3.x, only 2.7